# After passing Boolean Value from 0 to 1 nothing happened

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameter-passing

I am passing a `BOOL` Value from `GameViewController` to `ChooseLevelViewController`. If `BOOL = 0` the normal Image of my `Button1Pressed` in `ChooseLevel` should be shown. If `BOOL = 1` i want a other Image.

**My Code:**

**`ChooseLevel.h`**

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSomethingEnabled;
```

**`ChooseLevel.m`**

```
if (_isSomethingEnabled) {


[_button1Pressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonChanged.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**`GameView.m`**

```
#import "ChooseLevelViewController.h"
```

...

```
 ChooseLevelViewController *govc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chooseLevelViewController"];

        govc.isSomethingEnabled = 1;
        [self.finishAudio play];

        [self presentViewController:govc animated:NO completion:^(){
            [self.gameModel clearGameData];

        }];
```

Im testing with `NSLog`, the `boolValue` before passing is 0 after passing it is 1, works correctly. But my ButtonIcon doesn't change

Comment: `if (_isSomethingEnabled){change image}`, but `if !(_isSomethingEnabled)`, where do you (re)change the image?

Comment: Also note that you should use `YES` and `NO` instead of `1` and `0` for `BOOL` variables.

Comment: i thought 1/0 is the same as YES/NO? YES = 1, NO = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define a method which change your button image -

ChooseLevelViewController.h

```
-(void)loadButtonView;
```

loadButtonView definition

ChooseLevelViewController.m

```
-(void)loadButtonView
{
    [_button1Pressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: _isSomethingEnabled?@"buttonChanged.png":@"Button1Pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


ChooseLevelViewController *govc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chooseLevelViewController"];

        govc.isSomethingEnabled = 1;
       // Call below method for button image change
        [govc loadButtonView];

        [self.finishAudio play];

        [self presentViewController:govc animated:NO completion:^(){
            [self.gameModel clearGameData];

        }];
```

Hope this will be help your problem.